# Restrict what documents a user sees in a search

Tags: access

Whats the best way to setup sharepoint so that a user will only see documents searched for that they have access to? These documents could be on numerous subsites but the granularity is defined by sharepoint groups at the moment.
Is this even possible on a user group level?

Comment: Search results are automatically security trimmed. Users will only see what they have access to.

Answer (score 1):

By default, SharePoint search shows a user only the documents he/she has access to regardless of whether the permissions on those documents are defined explicitly for an individual or via a SharePoint group.

Comment: So if all the said documents are in the one document library,  can we set access rights per document that will then limit what users see when they search within that library? Some documents within our library are marked as confidential and should only be returned in a search if the user has access to that explicit file